# My Server Client program in C not correctly communicate

Tags: c, server, tcp, signals

My project's goal is to make little server-client program using only two signal-SIGUSR1, SIGUSR2.

Client works like this :

1. Check message's first bit (0 or 1).
2. If 0, send SIGUSR1. If 1, send SIGUSR2
3. pause() until server send SIGUSR1 or 2.

I put third step to guarantee every signal delivered well to server.

And, my server works like this :

1. Print server's pid (used by clinet's input)
2. Pause() infinitely (while(1) -> pause())
3. If signal received, sighandler works
4. Sighandler put 0 bit to string if SIGUSR1, else 1
5. pause() until another signal received.

But, my program don't works well. It's success depends on message's length.

ex)

Input

```
./client 11939 "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras efficitur scelerisque diam et placerat. Aenean lacinia facilisis egestas. Nulla fringilla velit sem, eu molestie odio porttitor id. Nulla et elit mollis, porta lorem at, cursus orci. Pellentesque id ultricies diam, in auctor erat. Nunc blandit lorem est, vitae pellentesque lacus tempus quis. Duis consectetur et mi in egestas. Sed vestibulum aliquet interdum. Duis quis neque vel erat placerat fermentum nec at lectus. In varius bibendum neque. Cras hendrerit mi vel tortor vestibulum finibus."
```

output

```
./server 11939 (won't print anything. 11939 is server's pid, which used running client)
```

I can only use usleep() or pause() function. I choose pause() because usleep() effect depends on computer environment.

Can somebody help? Here is my code :

Client

```
#include "minitalk.h"

s_info  *g_info;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pid_t           pid;
    int             len;
    struct  sigaction c_signal;

    if (!check_arg_error(argc, argv))
        return (0);

    g_info = (s_info *)malloc(sizeof(s_info));
    c_signal.sa_handler = sig_handler;
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &c_signal, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGUSR2, &c_signal, NULL);
    pid = atoi(argv[1]);
    len = strlen(argv[2]);
    send_int(pid, len);
    send_string(pid, argv[2], len);
}

int check_arg_error(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc != 3)
    {
        write(1, "usage : ./client [pid] [string]", 31);
        return (0);
    }
    if(!check_pid(argv[1]))
    {
        write(1, "usage : pid need to be number", 29);
        return (0);
    }
    return (1);
}

int check_pid(char *pid)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while(pid[i])
    {
        if(pid[i] > '9' || pid[i] < '0')
            return (0);
        i++;
    }
    return (1);
}

void    send_string(int pid, char *string, int len)
{
    unsigned char byte;
    int eight;
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while(i < len)
    {
        byte = string[i];
        eight = 9;
        while(--eight)
        {
            if(!check_first_bit(byte))
            {
                g_info->cur_sig = SIGUSR1;
                if (kill(pid, SIGUSR1) < 0)
                    s_error();
            }

            else
            {
                g_info->cur_sig = SIGUSR2;
                if (kill(pid, SIGUSR2) < 0)
                    s_error();
            }
            pause();
           byte = byte << 1;
        }
        i++;
    }
}

void    send_int(int pid, int num)
{
    int i;
    int check;

    i = 0;
    while(i++ < 32)
    {
        check = num >> 31;
        if(!check)
        {
            g_info->cur_sig = SIGUSR1;
            if (kill(pid, SIGUSR1) < 0)
                s_error();
        }

        else
        {
            g_info->cur_sig = SIGUSR2;
            if (kill(pid, SIGUSR2) < 0)
                s_error();
        }
        pause();
        num = num << 1;
    }
}


int check_first_bit(unsigned char byte)
{

    byte = byte >> 7;
    if (!byte)
        return(0);
    else
        return(1);
}

void    sig_handler(int signum)
{
    if (signum == g_info->cur_sig)
        return;
    else
    {
        write (1, "signal interrupt", 16);
        write (1, "\n", 1);
        exit(0);
    }
}

void    s_error(void)
{
    write (1, "signal error", 12);
    write (1, "\n", 1);
    exit(0);
}
```

Server

```
#include "minitalk.h"

s_info  *info;

int main(void)
{
    pid_t   pid;
    struct sigaction sa_signal;
    sigset_t    block_mask;

    info = (s_info*)malloc(sizeof(s_info));
    init_info();
    pid = getpid();
    print_pid(pid);
    sigemptyset(&block_mask);
    sigaddset(&block_mask, SIGUSR1);
    sigaddset(&block_mask, SIGUSR2);
    sa_signal.sa_mask = block_mask;
    sa_signal.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sa_signal.sa_handler = 0;
    sa_signal.sa_sigaction = sigusr_handler;
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa_signal, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGUSR2, &sa_signal, NULL);
    while(1)
        pause();
}

void    init_info(void)
{
    info->cnt = 0;
    info->len = 0;
    info->index = 0;
    info->num = 0;
    info->byte = 0;
    info->int_byte = 3;
}

void    print_pid(pid_t pid)
{
    int len;
    char    *c_pid;

    c_pid = ft_itoa(pid);
    len = strlen(c_pid);
    write(1, c_pid, len);
    write(1, "\n", 1);
    free(c_pid);
}

void    sigusr_handler(int signum, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *context)
{
    info->cnt++;
    if (siginfo->si_pid < 101)
        return;
    (void)context;
    if (info->cnt <= 32)
        make_len(signum);
    else
        make_string(signum);
    usleep(300);
    if (kill(siginfo->si_pid, signum) < 0)
        s_error();
}

void    make_len(int signum)
{
    int check;

    check = info->cnt % 8;

    if (signum == SIGUSR2)
        make_char();

    if (check == 0)
        make_int();

    if (info->cnt == 32)
    {
        info->len = info->num;
        info->res = (char *)malloc(info->len);
        info->num = 0;
        info->int_byte = 3;
    }
}

void    make_int(void)
{
    int temp;

    temp = (int)info->byte;
    if (info->int_byte != 0)
        temp <<= (info->int_byte * 8);
    info->num |= temp;
    info->byte = 0;
    info->int_byte--;
}


void    make_string(int signum)
{
    int check;

    check = info->cnt % 8;

    if (signum == SIGUSR2)
        make_char();

    if (check == 0)
    {
        info->res[info->index++] = info->byte;
        info->byte = 0;
    }

    if (info->len != 0 && info->index == info->len)
        print_string();
}

void    make_char(void)
{
    int check;

    check = info->cnt % 8;

    if (check == 0)
        info->byte |= 1;
    if (check == 7)
        info->byte |= 2;
    if (check == 6)
        info->byte |= 4;
    if (check == 5)
        info->byte |= 8;
    if (check == 4)
        info->byte |= 16;
    if (check == 3)
        info->byte |= 32;
    if (check == 2)
        info->byte |= 64;
    if (check == 1)
        info->byte |= 128;
}

void    print_string(void)
{
    char    *temp;

    temp = info->res;
    write (1, info->res, info->len);
    write (1, "\n", 1);
    free(info->res);
    init_info();
}

void    s_error(void)
{
    write(1, "signal error", 12);
    write(1, "\n", 1);
    exit(0);
}

char    *ft_itoa(int n)
{
    int     len;
    int     sign;
    int     i;
    char    *res;

    sign = 1;
    len = count_digit(n);
    check_minus(n, &len, &sign);
    res = (char *)malloc(len + 1);
    if (!res)
        return (0);
    res[len - 1] = n % 10 * sign + '0';
    n = n / 10 * sign;
    i = len - 2;
    while (n)
    {
        res[i--] = (n % 10) + '0';
        n /= 10;
    }
    if (sign < 0)
        res[0] = '-';
    res[len] = 0;
    return (res);
}

static int  count_digit(int n)
{
    int cnt;

    cnt = 0;
    if (n == 0)
        return (1);
    while (n)
    {
        n = n / 10;
        cnt++;
    }
    return (cnt);
}

static void check_minus(int n, int *len, int *sign)
{
    if (n < 0)
    {
        *len += 1;
        *sign = -1;
    }
}
```

Header

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>

#define CHECK_BYTE 4
typedef struct t_info
{
    int     cnt;
    int     len;
    int     index;
    int     num;
    int     int_byte;
    int     cur_sig;
    unsigned char   byte;
    char            *res;
} s_info;

//server
void    print_pid(pid_t pid);
void    init_info(void);
void    print_char(void);
void    make_char(void);
void    make_string(int signum);
void    print_string(void);
void    make_int(void);
void    make_len(int signum);
void    make_check(int signum);
void    sigusr_handler(int signum, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *contex);
char    *ft_itoa(int n);
static int  count_digit(int n);
static void check_minus(int n, int *len, int *sign);

//client
int check_arg_error(int argc, char **argv);
int check_pid(char *pid);
void    send_string(int pid, char *string, int len);
void    send_int(int pid, int num);
int    check_first_bit(unsigned char byte);
void    sig_handler(int signum);
void    s_error(void);
```

Makefile

```
CLIENT = client
SERVER = server

CC = gcc
FLAGS = -g -fsanitize=address -Wall -Werror -Wextra

INC = -I$(HEADER_DIR) -I$(LIBFT_DIR)

HEADER_DIR = .
HEADER_LIST = minitalk.h
HEADERS = $(addprefix $(HEADER_DIR), $(HEADER_LIST))

SRC_DIR = ./srcs/
S_SRC := server.c
S_OBJ = $(S_SRC:.c=.o)
C_SRC := client.c
C_OBJ = $(C_SRC:.c=.o)

all : $(SERVER) $(CLIENT)

$(SERVER) : $(LIBFT) $(S_OBJ)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $^ -o $@

$(CLIENT) :$(LIBFT) $(C_OBJ)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $^ -o $@

%.o : $(SRC_DIR)%.c $(HEADERS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ $(INC)

clean :
    @$(MAKE) -C $(LIBFT_DIR) clean
    @rm $(S_OBJ) $(C_OBJ)

fclean :
    @$(MAKE) -C $(LIBFT_DIR) fclean
    @rm $(S_OBJ) $(C_OBJ) $(SERVER) $(CLIENT)

bonus : all
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre], i.e. a program we can compile and run, the input you use, the actual output/behavior you get and the expected output/behavior. I did not check the code in detail, but I noticed that you use function `signal` to set up signal handlers. The semantics is implementation dependent. I suggest to use `sigaction` instead.

Comment: I edited my answer, and changed signal function to sigaction. Thank you for advice !

Comment: Your code is still not in a state that I could compile it without errors.

Comment: Oh I'm really sorry. I changed c files and added Makefile. You can compile program just type 'make'.

Comment: I think you should simplify your code to find the problems. As far as I understand, you want to send one of `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2` to transfer a single bit and wait for the same signal to be sent back as a confirmation. I suggest to start with a function that sends a single byte (`unsigned char`), send hard-coded bit patterns (bytes) first and check if this works as expected. Then build your functions `send_int` and `send_string` based on this byte-sending function. You can then test these by modifying the byte-sending to simply print the data. Extend your program step-by-step with testing.

Comment: I agree. Maybe l have to start everything from zero again. Thank you for helping! I really appreciate it.